# load() callback returns before loading is finished

Tags: jquery, callback, load

On my page, I have following document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
       var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #newdiv';        
       $('#mydiv').html('<p><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');
       $('#mydiv').load(toLoad, afterLoad());       

       function afterLoad() {
          alert('test');
       }         
       return false;        
    });
});
```

When a link is clicked, the content of `#newdiv` from the target link is loaded into `#mydiv` on the current page. Before loading, I replace the current content of `#mydiv` with an animated gif. When loading is finished, the animated gif disappears and in there goes the new content. All this is working perfectly.

However, after loading is finished, I want to execute a new function called `afterLoad`. For the moment, I've only added an `alert`. The strange thing is that the alert box appears when still showing the animated gif, so when the new content still is loading. Is there another way to execute `afterLoad` when the new content is already in place?

Answer (score 3):

change to:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #newdiv';        
    $('#mydiv').html('<p><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');
    $('#mydiv').load(toLoad, afterLoad);
 });
function afterLoad() {
   alert('test');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the function to run in the callback as a reference. Try this:

```
$('#mydiv').load(toLoad, afterLoad);  // Note the removal of ()
```